# How do I give Jenkins more heap space when it's running as a daemon on Amazon linux 2?

Tags: jenkins, centos, amazon-linux-2

I recently upgraded my Jenkins installation to version 2.432, and I'm facing an issue with finding the configuration file that was previously located at

> /etc/sysconfig/jenkins

Prior to this version, I could easily locate the file at that path, but it seems to be missing or relocated in the recent version.

I've checked the usual paths, but I couldn't find the configuration file. It's crucial for me to access this file to make necessary configurations.

Could someone please guide me on where the configuration file is located in Jenkins 2.432? Has there been a change in the default configuration file path or any new configuration file introduced in this version?

Comment: I have located the file path '/usr/share/jenkins/migrate', but despite making changes and restarting Jenkins, the modifications are not taking effect